# stuck trying to run IBridgePy on my M1 MacBook Air

Tags: python, apple-m1

I have installed python3.9 using home-brew and followed all the instructions as per IBridgePy videos. When I run the RUN_ME.py file I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/redwall/Desktop/IBridgePy_Mac_Python39_64/IBridgePy/IBCpp.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/redwall/Desktop/IBridgePy_Mac_Python39_64/IBridgePy/IBCpp.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/redwall/Desktop/IBridgePy_Mac_Python39_64/IBridgePy/IBCpp.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

When I run file$(which python) I get the following:

```
/usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/python (for architecture arm64e):  Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```

Is there any issue with the build or any idea on how can this import error be resolved?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you add a link to that specific YT video?

Comment: https://youtu.be/MCZcmxqDL94 This is the video